# While testing in javascript, Variables defined in 'before' block is showing undefined while using in 'It' block

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

This is a sample test where I am testing that testNum should be 0,

code:

```
describe("Test Contract", () => {
    
    before(async () => {
        const testNum = 0;
    })
    
    it("should be zero", function () {
        expect(testNum).to.equal(0);
    })
  }
```

But I am getting an error saying testNum is undefined.

Error:

```
1) Test Contract
       should be zero:
     ReferenceError: testNum is not defined
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `testNum` is scoped to the {} where you defined it. Also, `const` is used for read only values. I assume you want to reassign `testNum` multiple times. Therefore you should use `let`.

What you probably want is:

```
describe("Test Contract", () => {
    let testNum;
    before(async () => {
        testNum = 0;
    })
    
    it("should be zero", function () {
        expect(testNum).to.equal(0);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue, declaring variables in outer scope solves it.